# What is the best solution to work with archived HUGE amount of records in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I'm developing a project to gather ebanking transactions which is not online with .NET. 
It means that I'll get some text files containing the transactions for previous day. In total, it contains about 2,000,000 rows per day.

I want to have great performance in searching on the last month transactions (maximum 3 seconds), but I want to be able to search in the older transactions (maximum 30 seconds). Archive searching is based on `CardNumber`, `TransactionNumber`, and `TransactionDate`. I mean the archive search scenario is static and we don't want to search on the other columns or get any kind of reports.

I'm thinking of archiving strategy.

There are some options:

1. Tuning and optimizing indexes on the main table.
2. Partitioning the main table.
3. Moving old transactions to another database, nightly.
4. Moving old transactions to a text file, every hour (TextFile, XmlSerialization, BinarySerialization) and then search in memory.
5. Using other open source NON-RDBMS databases (like Lucene engine in text search).

First of all, I want to know which strategy is the best matching one for this scenario?

Also, how many records supported by known database engines (like SQL Server 2008, Oracle, Sqlite, MySql,...)? When should we think of Table Partitioning?

Comment: How many rows supported is not going to be a factor of the engine you choose, really - there is no theoretical limit except for the amount of space the rows occupy. This is going to be more a factor of your table design, architecture and hardware than anything else, if we're talking about the big players (Oracle, DB2, SQL Server) - switching between them in and of itself is not going to magically improve your ability to store more rows. I haven't heard a lot of high-capacity success stories regarding SqLite or MySQL, but I don't doubt that they may exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely think partitioning is going to work best here, probably monthly partitions. You can switch out old partitions (move them to separate filegroups over time, and mark them as read-only) but still have them available for querying. 2MM rows a day is not really all that huge, but if you're collecting that in the same partition forever some tasks/queries are eventually not going to scale. You need to be very diligent about how you set up your clustered index, non-clustered indexes, and partitioning scheme/function. If you're not already familiar with partitioning I strongly recommend budgeting some time to get familiar and become an expert with it in your test/dev/staging environments before letting it loose on production. [This is probably a good a starting point as any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180767.aspx), but don't be scared to search blogs for practical and real-world advice outside the official documentation as well.

Comment: I rarely need archived data. If I use table partitioning and store them in different filegroups, what is the best backup scenario? What happens if I loose a file in the filegroup (which contains old data)? Any idea about archiving in text file?

Comment: As you mark a filegroup as read-only, you can back it up once and then not include it as part of the backups from that point on. Not sure how you would lose a file but you would deal with that the same way you would deal with losing your primary backup. SQL Server doesn't really know what a text file is... you can BCP the data out, or write a program to extract the data and store it in a text file, but why wouldn't a backup be sufficient?